# Cant set array parameter value in jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I publish a report in jasper server.The report contains two parameter, `customer_id` and `query`. The parameter `query` is an array and its class is `java.util.List`. The report is working in `jasper soft studio`. But i cant set parameter in `jasperserver` please refer the below image

[image]

How can i set array parameter in that `query` field?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `java.util.Collection` instead of `java.util.List` as the class if you want to multi-select list values.
Refer to [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/jspetrak/entry/multi_select_input_controls_in) for detailed instructions.

If you wanna just have single select from the list then set the class to String or number.

Comment: I changed.But i cant type anything that field.

Comment: can you share screens of your input control selections on jasperserver

Comment: You want to type the parameter value ? why not select the parameter from   a drop down list

Comment: How to set drop down list value.? I don't know about that things?

Comment: Actually i am passing array of values from my controller page like `array(29,30,33)`

Comment: The values in the array ..are they predefined? And do you wanna select just one or multiple values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136227/discussion-between-bipin-and-malcolm-vaz).

Comment: Anybody know about this.?

Comment: The link Malcom points to is broken. this doesnt seem to be addressed yet.